# How to scroll to top in AMP after updating a state on successful form submission?

Tags: amp-html

I have created a sort functionality in my AMP page,now when I make a request to sort the results and when I update the state after successful form submission the page scroll position remains same. I want the page to scroll to top whenever the state is updated after sorting is done.

This is my code:

```
<form method="GET" 
          action="http://localhost:3001/api/v2/<%=@taxonomy%>/<%=@taxon%>" 
          action-xhr="http://localhost:3001/api/v2/<%=@taxonomy%>/<%=@taxon%>"
          target="_top" 
          on="submit-success: AMP.setState({
                        product_list: {
                        detail: event.response.detail
                        }
                    }),sort_lb.close();">
            <input type="hidden" name="sort" value="pop">
            <input type="submit" value="Popularity" class="sort_submit_btn">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place a html code **`<span id="ANY_ID"></span>`**

add a action and event : **`ANY_ID.scrollTo()`**

In your case :

```
on="submit-success: AMP.setState({
                        product_list: {
                        detail: event.response.detail
                        }
                    }),YOUR_ID.scrollTo(),sort_lb.close();">
```

An example of light-box close : [click here for view](https://codepen.io/bachchasingh/pen/NEwXyP)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into using [element-specific actions](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/interaction_dynamic/amp-actions-and-events#element-specific-actions) such as the [`scrollTo()`](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/interaction_dynamic/amp-actions-and-events#*-(all-elements)) action.

> **scrollTo(duration=INTEGER, position=STRING)**
>
> Scrolls an element into view with a smooth animation. If defined, `duration` specifies the length of the animation in milliseconds (default is 500ms). `position` is optional and takes one of `top`, `center` or `bottom` defining where in the viewport the element will be at the end of the scroll (default is `top`).