# Accelerated mobile page(AMP): On window scroll get the top position of the current viewport using javascript

Tags: javascript, amp-html

I am working on Accelerated mobile page(AMP). Here, on window scroll I want to get the top position of current scrolled viewport.

I have tried the below solutions:

```
 window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
   let ele = document.getElementById('amp-main-container');;
   console.log(ele.top)
 });
```

OR

```
 window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
   let ele = document.getElementById('amp-main-container');;
   console.log(ele.scrollTop)
 })
```

The amp-main-container is the parent folder of the structure
The console.log prints undefined on scroll.

I have also tried:

```
 window.addEventListener('scroll', function() {
   let ele = document.getElementById('amp-main-container');
   var viewportOffset = ele.getBoundingClientRect();
    console.log(viewportOffset.top)
 });
```

The above solution shows **ele.getBoundingClientRect is not a function** error.

I need to find the the viewport scrollTop position in AMP on scroll. Thank you.

Comment: did you read this page: https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/custom-javascript/

Comment: @JayGray As I can see the getBoundingClientRect() should be called as getBoundingClientRectAsync() which returns a promise which takes time to resolve. I need the viewport top position on scroll as I have to perform some action on scroll

Comment: I just want to find is there anyway where I can find the element position and viewport top position on scroll

Comment: are your willing to scroll to an #id (where #id could be a specific position in the viewport)?

Comment: @JayGray I have an id which is the main parent of all html structure. on scroll I need the top position of my viewport example I am at top of the page then my position is 0, if I scroll a little my top position is 100px and along with this I need an element position too.

Comment: Here are several ideas: 1) https://codepen.io/aghassemi/pen/ooKvav 2) https://amp.dev/documentation/examples/visual-effects/scroll_to_top/?referrer=ampbyexample.com and 3) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370461/how-to-scroll-to-top-in-amp-after-updating-a-state-on-successful-form-submission

Comment: @JayGray I wanted to check if my fixed button element overlaps on footer or not while scroll. Therefore I needed the element positions to check if overlap occurs or not so that i could change the position of my button if it comes to overlap on footer